# How does one determine if all messages in an Azure Queue have been processed?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-queues

I've just begun tinkering with Windows Azure and would appreciate help with a question.

How does one determine if a Windows Azure Queue is empty and that all work-items in it have been processed? If I have multiple worker processes querying a work-item queue, GetMessage(s) returns no messages if the queue is empty. But there is no guarantee that a currently invisible message will not be pushed back into the queue.

I need this functionality since follow-up behavior of my workflow depends on completion of all work-items in that particular queue. A possible way of tackling this problem would be to count the number of puts and deletes. But this will again require synchronization at a shared storage level and I would like to avoid it if possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the [ApproximateMessageCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.cloudqueue.approximatemessagecount) method. This should return the number of messages on the queue, including invisible messages (e.g. the ones being processed).

Mike Wood blogged about this subtlety, along with a tidbit about the queue's Clear method, [here](http://mvwood.com/blog/windows-azure-queue-tidbit/).

That said: you might want to choose a different mechanism for workflow management. Maybe a table row, where you have your rowkey equal to some multi-queue-item transation id, and individual properties being status flags. This allows you to track failed parts of the transaction (say, 9 out of 10 queue items process ok, the 10th fails; you can still delete the 10th queue item, but set its status flag to failed, then letting you deal with this scenario accordingly). Also: let's say you use the same queue to process another 'transaction' (meaning the queue is again non-zero in length). By using a separate object like a Table Row, you can still determine that your 'transaction' is complete even though there are additional queue messages.

Comment: Thanks David. This really helps. And thanks for the tip on maintaining the processing state in the table - I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: In addition to what David said, there is also a dequeue count that you can use for this purpose.

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to have another queue, call it termination indicator queue, and put a message in that queue for every message your process from your main queue. That is how it is done in research projects too. Check this out http://www.cs.gsu.edu/dimos/content/gis-vector-data-overlay-processing-azure-platform.html